# Add a title to gprofiler2 gosttable in R

Tags: r, ess

Hello I'm a new bioinformatician so bear with me please!
I'm using the [gprofiler2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gprofiler2/vignettes/gprofiler2.html#gene-list-functional-enrichment-analysis-with-gost) to run GO/KEGG analysis in R using emacs/ess and I want to add a title to the table it offers:

```
publish_gosttable(gostres, highlight_terms = gostres$result[c(1:2,10,120),],
                        use_colors = TRUE, 
                        show_columns = c("source", "term_name", "term_size", "intersection_size"),
                        filename = NULL)
```

I have tried the `title()`, `tab_header()` function but I can't seem to be able to add a title. My question is if there is some other function or package that would allow me to add it instead of having to do it manually.

The code so far

```
GOresult <- gost(
geneid1up$gene,
organism = "hsapiens",
ordered_query = FALSE, 
multi_query = FALSE,
significant = TRUE, 
exclude_iea = FALSE,
measure_underrepresentation = FALSE,
evcodes = FALSE,
user_threshold = 0.05,
correction_method =  "gSCS",
domain_scope = "annotated",
custom_bg = NULL,
numeric_ns = "",
sources = c("GO:BP","GO:MF","GO:CC","KEGG"),
as_short_link = FALSE)

GOresult1 <- as.data.frame(GOresult$result)
GOresult1$minuslog10pval <- -log10(GOresult1$p_value)
names(GOresult1)[15] <- "-log10(pval)"
GOresult2 <- GOresult1[order(GOresult1$p_value, decreasing=F),]

plot1 <- publish_gosttable(GOresult2, highlight_terms = GOresult2[c(1:20),],
                        use_colors = FALSE, 
                        show_columns = c("source", "term_name", "term_size", "intersection_size","-log10(pval)"),
                        filename = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do the job?

```
    library(gprofiler2)
library(ggplot2)
gostres <- gost(query = c("X:1000:1000000", "rs17396340", "GO:0005005", "ENSG00000156103", "NLRP1"), 
                organism = "hsapiens", ordered_query = FALSE, 
                multi_query = FALSE, significant = TRUE, exclude_iea = FALSE, 
                measure_underrepresentation = FALSE, evcodes = FALSE, 
                user_threshold = 0.05, correction_method = "g_SCS", 
                domain_scope = "annotated", custom_bg = NULL, 
                numeric_ns = "", sources = NULL, as_short_link = FALSE)

publish_gosttable(gostres, highlight_terms = gostres$result[c(1:2,10,120),],
                  use_colors = TRUE, 
                  show_columns = c("source", "term_name", "term_size", "intersection_size"),
                  filename = NULL)+
  ggtitle('Your Title')
```

Result:

[image]

The trick is that the plot is a ggplot objet. Therefore you can add the title using `+ggtitle('Your Title')` after your plot code (as in my example)

Comment: Hello this was a very helpful comment although in my case im not looking to save the plot it offers, just the table! I have altered my post and added my code so far so you can see i have tampered a little bit with it. The result when running "plot1" is simply the table without the plot above it and i want to add a title to it. Adding the ggtitle here give me the error "invalid argument to unary operator".

Comment: Can you provide what's in ```geneid1up$gene``` if it's not to big so I can try on my side?

Comment: @AggelosKozonakis I tried your the function you're using with +ggtitle() and it seems to works, see updated answer above

Comment: Yes this works perfect! Thank you very much, i think i placed the +ggtitle() wrong and thats why it didnt produce the title.

Comment: @AggelosKozonakis Perfect :) if you though this helpful you can validate the answer so it helps other users

Comment: Sorry new to stackoverflow! Hope i validated it, sadly i cant upvote your answer yet.

Comment: it's fine don't worry :) thanks!